# How can I dynamically create class methods for a class in python

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming, static-methods, setattr

If I define a little python program as

```
class a():
    def _func(self):
        return "asdf"

    # Not sure what to resplace __init__ with so that a.func will return asdf
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         setattr(self, 'func', classmethod(self._func))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a.func
```

I receive the traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setattr_static.py", line 9, in <module>
    a.func
AttributeError: class a has no attribute 'func'
```

What I am trying to figure out is, how can I dynamically set a class method to a class without instantiating an object?

---

### Edit:

The answer for this problem is

```
class a():
    pass

def func(cls, some_other_argument):
    return some_other_argument

setattr(a, 'func', classmethod(func))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(a.func)
    print(a.func("asdf"))
```

returns the following output

```
<bound method type.func of <class '__main__.a'>>
asdf
```

Comment: Take a look at *class methods*. Static methods in python aren't the same as in C++.

Comment: You aren't calling `__init__()` anywhere, so it's not a big surprise it's not getting executed.  Moreover, you would have to add the new method on the *class*, not on the *instance*.

Comment: Something like `a.func = staticmethod(a._func)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach How can I dynamically set a classmethod without instantiating an object?

Comment: the Edit above contains an error: in setattr, replace "some_other_argument" by "func"

Comment: The marked duplicate is about adding methods to individual instances, not to classes

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can dynamically add a classmethod to a class by simple assignment to the class object or by setattr on the class object. Here I'm using the python convention that classes start with capital letters to reduce confusion:

```
# define a class object (your class may be more complicated than this...)
class A(object):
    pass

# a class method takes the class object as its first variable
def func(cls):
    print 'I am a class method'

# you can just add it to the class if you already know the name you want to use
A.func = classmethod(func)

# or you can auto-generate the name and set it this way
the_name = 'other_func' 
setattr(A, the_name, classmethod(func))
```

Answer (score 11):

There are a couple of problems here:

- `__init__` is only run when you create an instance, e.g. `obj = a()`.  This means that when you do `a.func`, the `setattr()` call hasn't happened
- You cannot access the attributes of a class directly from within methods of that class, so instead of using just `_func` inside of `__init__` you would need to use `self._func` or `self.__class__._func`
- `self` will be an instance of `a`, if you set an attribute on the instance it will only be available for that instance, not for the class.  So even after calling `setattr(self, 'func', self._func)`, `a.func` will raise an AttributeError
- Using `staticmethod` the way you are will not do anything, `staticmethod` will return a resulting function, it does not modify the argument.  So instead you would want something like `setattr(self, 'func', staticmethod(self._func))` (but taking into account the above comments, this still won't work)

So now the question is, what are you actually trying to do?  If you really want to add an attribute to a class when initializing an instance, you could do something like the following:

```
class a():
    def _func(self):
        return "asdf"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        setattr(self.__class__, 'func', staticmethod(self._func))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = a()
    a.func
    a.func()
```

However, this is still kind of weird.  Now you can access `a.func` and call it without any problems, but the `self` argument to `a.func` will always be the most recently created instance of `a`.  I can't really think of any sane way to turn an instance method like `_func()` into a static method or class method of the class.

Since you are trying to dynamically add a function to the class, perhaps something like the following is closer to what you are actually trying to do?

```
class a():
    pass

def _func():
    return "asdf"

a.func = staticmethod(_func)  # or setattr(a, 'func', staticmethod(_func))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a.func
    a.func()
```

Comment: I just clarified my question a bit. I want to be able to call a class method without having to explicitly define it.

Comment: See my edit, the final piece of code may be what you are looking for.

Comment: If multiple modules call this module, will staticmethod(_func) be called once for each import, or just once for the life of the module?

Comment: At last code sample: only once at module load.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `setattr(self, 'func', staticmethod(self._func))`

You need to initialize class `variable=a()` to call `__init__`
There is no init in static class

Comment: I receive the same traceback error if I do that.

Comment: I am pretty sure I need to use classmethod, but your method of doing so is not working for me.

Comment: this method aplies on instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way

```
class a():
    def _func(self):
        return "asdf"

setattr(a, 'func', staticmethod(a._func))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a.func()
```

Comment: If this was put into use in a module, would setattr be called everytime I use the class a?

Comment: only at first module import

Comment: So if multiple modules call this module, it will only call setattr once?

Comment: Only once, second and more module import connects to namespace.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. It tries to make _func both an object method and a class method. It would have been better just to use `@classmethod` on _func.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. The basic idea: use an extra class to hold the methods

I found a meaningful way to do the work:

First, we define such a BaseClass:

```
class MethodPatcher:
    @classmethod
    def patch(cls, target):
        for k in cls.__dict__:
            obj = getattr(cls, k)
            if not k.startswith('_') and callable(obj):
                setattr(target, k, obj)
```

Now that we have an original class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def a(self):
        print('a')
```

Then we define the new method which we want to add on a new `Patcher` class:

*(Do not make the method name starts with an `_` in this case)*

```
class MyPatcher(MethodPatcher):
    def b(self):
        print('b')
```

Then call:

```
MyPatcher.patch(MyClass)
```

So, you'll find the new method `b(self)` is added to the original `MyClass`:

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.a()  # which prints an 'a'
obj.b()  # which prints a 'b'
```

#### 2. Make the syntax less verbose, we use class decorator

Now if we have the `MethodPatcher` decalred, we need to do two things:

- define a child class `ChildClass` of `ModelPatcher` which contains the extra methods to add
- call `ChildClass.patch(TargetClass)`

So we soon found that the second step can be simplified by using a decorator:

We define a decorator:

```
def patch_methods(model_class):
    def do_patch(cls):
        cls.patch(model_class)
    return do_patch
```

And we can use it like:

```
@patch_methods(MyClass)
class MyClassPatcher(MethodPatcher):

    def extra_method_a(self):
        print('a', self)

    @classmethod
    def extra_class_method_b(cls):
        print('c', cls)

    # !!ATTENTION!! the effect on declaring staticmethod here may not work as expected:
    # calling this method on an instance will take the self into the first argument.
    # @staticmethod
    # def extra_static_method_c():
    #    print('c')
```

#### 3. Wrap together

So, we can now put the definition of `MethodPatcher` and `patch_method` into a single module:

```
# method_patcher.py

class MethodPatcher:
    @classmethod
    def patch(cls, target):
        for k in cls.__dict__:
            obj = getattr(cls, k)
            if not k.startswith('_') and callable(obj):
                setattr(target, k, obj)

def patch_methods(model_class):
    def do_patch(cls):
        cls.patch(model_class)
    return do_patch
```

So we can use it freely:

```
from method_patcher import ModelPatcher, patch_model
```

#### 4. Final solution: More simple declaration

Soon I found that the `MethodPatcher` class is not nessesary, while the `@patch_method` decorator can do the work, so **FINALLY** we only need a `patch_method`:

```
def patch_methods(model_class):
    def do_patch(cls):
        for k in cls.__dict__:
            obj = getattr(cls, k)
            if not k.startswith('_') and callable(obj):
                setattr(model_class, k, obj)
    return do_patch
```

And the usage becomes:

```
@patch_methods(MyClass)
class MyClassPatcher:

    def extra_method_a(self):
        print('a', self)

    @classmethod
    def extra_class_method_b(cls):
        print('c', cls)

    # !!ATTENTION!! the effect on declaring staticmethod here may not work as expected:
    # calling this method on an instance will take the self into the first argument.
    # @staticmethod
    # def extra_static_method_c():
    #    print('c')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Python 2.7.5, and I wasn't able to get the above solutions working for me. This is what I ended up with:

```
# define a class object (your class may be more complicated than this...)
class A(object):
    pass

def func(self):
    print 'I am class {}'.format(self.name)

A.func = func

# using classmethod() here failed with:
#       AttributeError: type object '...' has no attribute 'name'
```