# Python: Dynamically add properties to class instance, properties return function value with inputs

Tags: python

I've been going through all the Stackoverflow answers on dynamic property setting, but for whatever reason I can't seem to get this to work.

I have a class, `Evolution_Base`, that in its `init` creates an instance of `Value_Differences`. `Value_Differences` should be dynamically creating `properties`, based on the list I pass, that returns the function value from `_get_df_change`:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd
class Evolution_Base():
    
    def __init__(self, res_date_0 : DataFrame , res_date_1 : DataFrame):
        
        @dataclass
        class Results_Data():          
            res_date_0_df : DataFrame               
            res_date_1_df : DataFrame
            
    
        self.res = Results_Data(res_date_0_df= res_date_0,
                                res_date_1_df= res_date_1)
        
        property_list = ['abc', 'xyz']
        self.difference = Value_Differences(parent = self, property_list=property_list)
        
    
    # Shared Functions
    def _get_df_change(self, df_name, operator = '-'):
        df_0 = getattr(self.res.res_date_0_df, df_name.lower())
        df_1 = getattr(self.res.res_date_1_df, df_name.lower())
        return self._df_change(df_1, df_0, operator=operator)
        
    def _df_change(self, df_1 : pd.DataFrame, df_0 : pd.DataFrame, operator = '-') -> pd.DataFrame:
        """
        Returns df_1 <operator | default = -> df_0
        """        
        # is_numeric mask
        m_1 = df_1.select_dtypes('number')
        m_0 = df_0.select_dtypes('number')
        
        def label_me(x):
            x.columns = ['t_1', 't_0']
            return x
        
        if operator == '-':
            return label_me(df_1[m_1] - df_0[m_0])
        elif operator == '+':
            return label_me(df_1[m_1] + df_0[m_0])
        
        
class Value_Differences():    
    def __init__(self, parent : Evolution_Base, property_list = []):
        self._parent = parent
    
        for name in property_list:
                        
            def func(self, prop_name):
                return self._parent._get_df_change(name)
            
            # I've tried the following... 
            setattr(self, name, property(fget = lambda cls_self: func(cls_self, name)))
            setattr(self, name, property(func(self, name)))
            setattr(self, name, property(func))
```

Its driving me nuts... Any help appreciated!

My desired outcome is for:

```
evolution = Evolution_Base(df_1, df_2)
evolution.difference.abc == evolution._df_change('abc')
evolution.difference.xyz == evolution._df_change('xyz')
```

EDIT:  The simple question is really, how do I setattr for a property *function*?

Comment: There's no reason to redefine `Results_Data` for every instance of `Evolution_Base`: just define it globally.

Comment: Its been a couple days since I've looked at this code of mine, but I'm thinking that I have a variable naming issue in the 'for name in property_list' part...

Comment: I'm not really sure what data to provide though?   The question is pretty similar to this quesiton I asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74710722/python-dynamic-classmethod-creation-from-dictionary).     However this time I'm trying to do it with a property.

Comment: Show the expected input (df_1, df_2) and output.

Comment: Kind of a sidenote, but I doubt you actually want to specify `property_list = []` as a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). Perhaps you meant `property_list: list`?

Comment: @CrazyChucky yeah, you're probably right!  I knew it was bad form lol.

Comment: I don't know your use case, so this might be  a stupid question, but is there a reason you don't define the change-getting method on `Value_Difference`, if that's the route by which you want to access it? If it's the main thing you're using `Value_Difference` for and you don't want t keep typing a method name, you could even define it as `__call__`. Then it would be as simple as `evolution.difference('xyz')`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I *think* when I wrote this I was planning on a couple different Value_Difference-like classes that all shared the change-getting method.  But honestly, I kind of shoot-from-the-hip code, so who knows :)

Comment: @keynesiancross can you explain why do you want to do it? In my opinion, using python to dynamically set attributes on a class causes a lot of maintenance problems for the code base, and I would really think to reconsider if you want to do this. For example, you can create all possible properties (assuming it's a defined list), and make them return `None` or some other indication for no-difference.
It will also create a much more clear api for those who interact with this class, so they won't get possible `AttributeErrors` in the future

Comment: @BarakFatal that's a fair point. I was simply trying to avoid a lot of copy-paste in my code of similar properties,  where the only difference was each property called a shared function with a different input variable.  Almost like I wanted to zip(input_arg, function_to_call_with_input_arg)

Comment: @keynesiancross To be honest I believe that it's not worth the tradeoff for a dyanmic code block like that. Just as much as it's hard for you now, it will be hard to everyone in your team/company. Not to talk about stuff like autocompletion in your IDE which will not be available, typing problems and potential attribute errors.
I will go on writing everything I can, and perhaps extracting it to an abstract class for less code duplication.
My philosopy is that if you can't do dynamic stuff like that in Java for example (or any other static typing language), you shouldn't do it in python

Comment: I appreciate the thoughts @BarakFatal, and yeah I'm going to give up on this.   I wish I knew Java, I'm a team of one just trying to figure python out along the way! This has all been very helpful

Comment: I rolled back your most recent edit because this is **not a discussion forum**. We want questions to address the countless people who will find the question later with a search engine, not the few random volunteers who tried to answer it.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite the rabbit hole. Impossible is a big call, but I will say this: they don't intend you to do this. The 'Pythonic' way of achieving your example use case is the `__getattr__` method. You could also override the `__dir__` method to insert your custom attributes for discoverability.

This is the code for that:

```
class Value_Differences():
    def __init__(self, parent : Evolution_Base, property_list = []):
        self._parent = parent
        self._property_list = property_list

    def __dir__(self):
        return sorted(set(
               dir(super(Value_Differences, self)) + \
               list(self.__dict__.keys()) + self._property_list))

    def __getattr__(self, __name: str):
        if __name in self._property_list:
            return self._parent._get_df_change(__name)
```

But that *wasn't the question*, and respect for a really, really interesting question. This is one of those things that you look at and say 'hmm, should be possible' and can get almost to a solution. I initially thought what you asked for was *technically* possible, just very hacky to achieve. But it turns out that it would be very, very weird hackery if it was possible.

Two small foundational things to start with:

1. Remind ourselves of the hierarchy of Python objects that the runtime is working with when defining and instantiating classes:

- The metaclass (defaulting to `type`), which is used to build classes. I'm going to refer to this as the Metaclass Type Object (MTO).
- The class definition, which is used to build objects. I'm going to refer to this as the Class Type Object (CTO).
- And the class instance or object, which I'll refer to as the Class Instance Object (CIO).

MTOs are subclasses of `type`. CTOs are subclasses of `object`. CIOs are instances of CTOs, but instantiated by MTOs.

2. Python runs code inside class definitions as if it was running a function:

```
class Class1:
  print("1")
  def __init__(self, v1):
    print("4")
  print("2")
print("3")
c1 = Class1("x")
print("5")
```

gives 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Put these two things together with:

```
class Class1:
  def attr1_get(self):
    return 'attr1 value'
  attr1 = property(attr1_get)
```

we are defining a function attr1_get as part of the class definition. We are then running an inline piece of code that creates an object of type `property`. Note that this is just the name of the object's type - it isn't a property as you would describe it. Just an object with some attributes, being references to various functions. We then assign that object to an attribute in the class we are defining.

In the terms I used above, once that code is run we have a CTO instantiated as an object in memory that contains an attribute `attr1` of type `property` (an object subclass, containing a bunch of attributes itself - one of which is a reference to the function `attr1_get`).

That can be used to instantiate an object, the CIO.

This is where the MTO comes in. You instantiate the property object while defining the CTO so that when the runtime applies the MTO to create the CIO from the CTO, an attribute on the CIO will be formed with a custom getter function for that attribute rather than the 'standard' getter function the runtime would use. The `property` object means something to the `type` object when it is building a new `object`.

So when we run:

```
c1 = Class1()
```

we don't get a CIO `c1` with an attribute `attr1` that is an object of type `property`. The metaclass of type `type` formed a set of references against the attribute's internal state to all the functions we stored in the `property` object. Note that this is happening inside the runtime, and you can't call this directly from your code - you just tell the `type` metaclass to do it by using the `property` wrapper object.

So if you directly assign a `property()` result to an attribute of a CIO, you have a Pythonic object assigned that references some functions, but the internal state for the runtime to use to reference the getter, setter, etc. is not set up. The getter of an attribute that contains a property object is the standard getter and so returns the object instance, and not the result of the functions it wraps,

This next bit of code demonstrates how this flows:

```
print("Let's begin")

class MetaClass1(type):
    print("Starting to define MetaClass1")

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        print("Metaclass1 __new__({})".format(str(cls)))
        return x
    
    print("__new__ of MetaClass1 is defined")

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print("Metaclass1 __init__({})".format(str(cls)))

    print("__init__ of MetaClass1 is defined")

print("Metaclass is defined")

class Class1(object,metaclass=MetaClass1):
    print("Starting to define Class1")

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Class1 __new__({})".format(str(cls)))
        return super(Class1, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    print("__new__ of Class1 is defined")

    def __init__(self):
        print("Class1 __init__({})".format(str(self)))

    print("__init__ of Class1 is defined")

    def g1(self):
        return 'attr1 value'

    print("g1 of Class1 is defined")

    attr1 = property(g1)

    print("Class1.attr1 = ", attr1)

    print("attr1 of Class1 is defined")

    def addProperty(self, name, getter):
        setattr(self, name, property(getter))
        print("self.", name, " = ", getattr(self, name))

    print("addProperty of Class1 is defined")

print("Class is defined")

c1 = Class1()

print("Instance is created")

print(c1.attr1)

def g2(cls):
    return 'attr2 value'

c1.addProperty('attr2', g2)

print(c1.attr2)
```

I have put all those print statements there to demonstrate the order in which things happen very clearly.

In the middle, you see:

```
g1 of Class1 is defined
Class1.attr1 =  <property object at 0x105115c10>
attr1 of Class1 is defined
```

We have created an object of type `property` and assigned it to a class attribute.

Continuing:

```
addProperty of Class1 is defined
Metaclass1 __new__(<class '__main__.MetaClass1'>)
Metaclass1 __init__(<class '__main__.Class1'>)
Class is defined
```

The metaclass got instantiated, being passed first itself (`__new__`) and then the class it will work on (`__init__`). This happened right as we stepped out of the class definition. I have only included the metaclass to show what will happen with the `type` metaclass by default.

Then:

```
Class1 __new__(<class '__main__.Class1'>)
Class1 __init__(<__main__.Class1 object at 0x105124c10>)
Instance is created
attr1 value
self. attr2  =  <property object at 0x105115cb0>
<property object at 0x105115cb0>
```

`Class1` is instantiated, providing first its type to `__new__` and then its instance to `__init__`.

We see that `attr1` is instantiated properly, but `attr2` is not. That is because `setattr` is being called once the class instance is already constructed and is just saying `attr2` is an instance of the class `property` and not defining `attr2` as the actual runtime construct of a property.

Which is made more clear if we run:

```
print(c1.attr2.fget(c1))
print(c1.attr1.fget(c1))
```

`attr2` (a property object) isn't aware of the class or instance of the containing attribute's parent. The function it wraps still needs to be given the instance to work on.

`attr1` doesn't know what to do with that, because as far as it is concerned it is a string object, and has no concept of how the runtime is mapping its getter.

Comment: thanks for giving it a go!  So you dont think it's possible?

Comment: Impossible is a big call. A good bit of the time since answering above I've spent reading the source code of the Python runtime environment. Properties are fascinating. To achieve what you want (dynamic creation of a class attribute that is a wrapped getter function, directly instantiated on an existing class instance) requires two things that seem mutually exclusive. I'll edit my answer to explain, but it will take a bit of typing!

Comment: oh my. . . here I was thinking this would be a case of some very specific lambda setup being able to do the trick. . . I didn't think  I would get source code involved!

Comment: and all this simply because I kind how 'clean' it looks when using properties (where the result is static per class instance) vs all these function calls in my code

Answer (score 4):

### As asked

> how do I setattr for a property *function*?

To be usable as a `property`, the accessor function needs to be wrapped as a property and then assigned as an attribute **of the class, not** the instance.

That function, meanwhile, needs to have a single **unbound** parameter - which will be an instance of the class, but is **not** necessarily the current `self`. Its logic needs to use the current value of `name`, but [late binding will be an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290) because of the desire to [create lambdas in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676).

A clear and simple way to work around this is to define a helper function accepting the `Value_Differences` instance and the `name` to use, and then [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/) the `name` value eagerly.

Naively:

```
from functools import partial

def _get_from_parent(name, instance):
    return instance._parent._get_df_change(name)

class Value_Differences:    
    def __init__(self, parent: Evolution_Base, property_list = []):
        self._parent = parent
    
        for name in property_list:            
            setattr(Value_Differences, name, property(
                fget = partial(_get_from_parent, name)
            ))
```

However, this of course has the issue that **every** instance of `Value_Differences` will set properties **on the class**, thus modifying what properties are available **for each other instance**. Further, in the case where there are many instances that should have the same properties, *the setup work will be repeated at each instance creation*.

---

### The apparent goal

It seems that what is really sought, is the ability to **create classes dynamically**, such that a list of property names is provided and a corresponding class pops into existence, with code filled in for the properties implementing a certain logic.

There are multiple approaches to this.

#### Factory A: Adding properties to an instantiated template

Just like how functions can be nested within each other and the inner function will be an object that can be modified and `return`ed (as is common [when creating a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654)), a class body can appear within a function and a new class object (with the same name) is created every time the function runs. (The code in the OP already does this, for the `Results_Data` dataclass.)

```
def example():
    class Template:
        pass
    return Template

>>> TemplateA, TemplateB = example(), example()
>>> TemplateA is TemplateB
False
>>> isinstance(TemplateA(), TemplateB)
False
>>> isinstance(TemplateB(), TemplateA)
False
```

So, a "factory" for value-difference classes could look like

```
from functools import partial

def _make_value_comparer(property_names, access_func):
    class ValueDifferences:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self._parent = parent
    for name in property_names:
        setattr(Value_Differences, name, property(
            fget = partial(access_func, name)
        ))
    return ValueDifferences
```

Notice that instead of hard-coding a helper, this factory expects to be provided with a function that implements the access logic. That function takes two parameters: a property name, and the `ValueDifferences` instance. (They're in that order because it's more convenient for `functools.partial` usage.)

#### Factory B: Using the `type` constructor directly

The built-in `type` in Python has two entirely separate functions.

With one argument, it discloses the type of an object.
With three arguments, it creates a new type. The `class` syntax is in fact syntactic sugar for a call to this builtin. The arguments are:

- a string name (will be set as the `__name__` attribute)
- a list of classes to use as superclasses (will be set as `__bases__`)
- a dict mapping attribute names to their values (including methods and properties - will become the `__dict__`, roughly)

In this style, the same factory could look something like:

```
from functools import partial

def _make_value_comparer(property_names, access_func):
    methods = {
        name: property(fget = partial(access_func, name)
        for name in property_names
    }
    methods['__init__'] = lambda self, parent: setattr(self, '_parent', parent)
    return type('ValueDifferences', [], methods)
```

#### Using the factory

In either of the above cases, `EvolutionBase` would be modified in the same way.

Presumably, every `EvolutionBase` should use the same `ValueDifferences` class (i.e., the one that specifically defines `abc` and `xyz` properties), so the `EvolutionBase` class can cache that class as a class attribute, and use it later:

```
class Evolution_Base():
    def _get_from_parent(name, mvd):
        # mvd._parent will be an instance of Evolution_Base.
        return mvd._parent._get_df_change(name)

    _MyValueDifferences = _make_value_comparer(['abc', 'xyz'], _get_from_parent)

    def __init__(self, res_date_0 : DataFrame , res_date_1 : DataFrame):        
        @dataclass
        class Results_Data():          
            res_date_0_df : DataFrame               
            res_date_1_df : DataFrame
    
        self.res = Results_Data(res_date_0_df= res_date_0,
                                res_date_1_df= res_date_1)
        
        self.difference = _MyValueDifferences(parent = self)
```

Notice that the cached `_MyValueDifferences` class no longer requires a list of property names to be constructed. That's because it was already provided **when the class** was created. The actual thing that varies per instance of `_MyValueDifferences`, is the `parent`, so that's all that gets passed.

---

### Simpler approaches

It seems that the goal is to have a class whose instances are tightly associated with instances of `Evolution_Base`, providing properties specifically named `abc` and `xyz` that are computed using the `Evolution_Base`'s data.

That could just be hard-coded as a nested class:

```
class Evolution_Base:
    class EBValueDifferences:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self._parent = parent

        @property
        def abc(self):
            return self._parent._get_df_change('abc')

        @property
        def xyz(self):
            return self._parent._get_df_change('xyz')

    def __init__(self, res_date_0 : DataFrame , res_date_1 : DataFrame):        
        @dataclass
        class Results_Data():          
            res_date_0_df : DataFrame               
            res_date_1_df : DataFrame
        self.res = Results_Data(res_date_0_df = res_date_0,
                                res_date_1_df = res_date_1)
        self.difference = EBValueDifferences(self)

    # _get_df_change etc. as before
```

Even simpler, provide corresponding properties directly on `Evolution_Base`:

```
class Evolution_Base:
    @property
    def abc_difference(self):
        return self._get_df_change('abc')

    @property
    def xyz_difference(self):
        return self._get_df_change('xyz')

    def __init__(self, res_date_0 : DataFrame , res_date_1 : DataFrame):        
        @dataclass
        class Results_Data():          
            res_date_0_df : DataFrame               
            res_date_1_df : DataFrame
        self.res = Results_Data(res_date_0_df = res_date_0,
                                res_date_1_df = res_date_1)

    # _get_df_change etc. as before

# client code now calls my_evolution_base.abc_difference
# instead of my_evolution_base.difference.abc
```

If there are a lot of such properties, they could be attached using a **much simpler** dynamic approach (that would still be reusable for other classes that define a `_get_df_change`):

```
def add_df_change_property(name, cls):
    setattr(
        cls, f'{name}_difference',
        property(fget = lambda instance: instance._get_df_change(name))
    )
```

which can also be adapted for use as a decorator:

```
from functools import partial

def exposes_df_change(name):
    return partial(add_df_change_property, name)

@exposes_df_change('abc')
@exposes_df_change('def')
class Evolution_Base:
    # `self.difference` can be removed, no other changes needed
```

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental reason why what you tried doesn't work is that a property, a use case of a descriptor, by design must be stored as a class variable, not as an instance attribute.

Excerpt from the [documentation of descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#simple-example-a-descriptor-that-returns-a-constant):

> To use the descriptor, it must be stored as a **class variable** in
> another class:

To create a class with dynamically named properties that has access to a parent class, one elegant approach is to create the class within a method of the main class, and use `setattr` to create class attributes with dynamic names and property objects. A class created in the closure of a method automatically has access to the `self` object of the parent instance, avoiding having to manage a clunky `_parent` attribute like you do in your attempt:

```
class Evolution_Base:
    def __init__(self, property_list):
        self.property_list = property_list
        self._difference = None

    @property
    def difference(self):
        if not self._difference:
            class Value_Differences:
                pass
            for name in self.property_list:
                # use default value to store the value of name in each iteration
                def func(obj, prop_name=name):
                    return self._get_df_change(prop_name) # access self via closure
                setattr(Value_Differences, name, property(func))
            self._difference = Value_Differences()
        return self._difference

    def _get_df_change(self, df_name):
        return f'df change of {df_name}' # simplified return value for demo purposes
```

so that:

```
evolution = Evolution_Base(['abc', 'xyz'])
print(evolution.difference.abc)
print(evolution.difference.xyz)
```

would output:

```
df change of abc
df change of xyz
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ExtralargeNaturalCoordinate

Comment: Do you think there would be a way of doing this without recreating the Value_Differences class and rebuilding a function for each name in the property_list each time that .difference is called?

Comment: Indeed. You can cache the instance of `Value_Differences` in an instance attribute. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 2):

Responding directly to your question, you can create a class:

```py
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self, props):
        def make_prop(name):
            return property(lambda accessor_self: self._prop_impl(name))

        self.accessor = type(
            'Accessor',
            tuple(),
            {p: make_prop(p) for p in props}
        )()

    def _prop_impl(self, arg):
        return arg


o = FooBar(['foo', 'bar'])

assert o.accessor.foo == o._prop_impl('foo')
assert o.accessor.bar == o._prop_impl('bar')
```

Further, it would be beneficiary to cache created class to make equivalent objects more similar and eliminate potential issues with equality comparison.

That said, I am not sure if this is desired.  There's little benefit of replacing method call syntax (`o.f('a')`) with property access (`o.a`).  I believe it can be detrimental on multiple accounts: dynamic properties are confusing, harder to document, etc., finally while none of this is strictly guaranteed in crazy world of dynamic python -- they kind of communicate wrong message: that the access is cheap and does not involve computation and that perhaps you can attempt to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you define the function func in the loop, it closes over the current value of the name variable, not the value of the name variable at the time the property is accessed. To fix this, you can use a lambda function to create a closure that captures the value of name at the time the property is defined.

```
class Value_Differences():    
    def __init__(self, parent : Evolution_Base, property_list = []):
        self._parent = parent
    
        for name in property_list:
                        
            setattr(self, name, property(fget = lambda self, name=name: self._parent._get_df_change(name)))
```

Does this help you ?

Comment: let me give this a try and come back to you

Answer (score 0):

The simple question is really, how do I setattr for a property function?

In python we can set dynamic attributes like this:

```
class DynamicProperties():
    def __init__(self, property_list):
        self.property_list = property_list
    def add_properties(self):
        for name in self.property_list:
             setattr(self.__class__, name, property(fget=lambda self: 1))
            
dync = DynamicProperties(['a', 'b'])
dync.add_properties()
print(dync.a) # prints 1
print(dync.b) # prints 1
```

Correct me if I am wrong but from reviewing your code, you want to create a dynamic attributes then set their value to a specific function call within the same class, where the passed in data is passed in attributes in the constructor " **init** "  this is achievable, an example:

```
class DynamicProperties():
    def __init__(self, property_list, data1, data2):
        self.property_list = property_list
        self.data1 = data1
        self.data2 = data2
    def add_properties(self):
        for name in self.property_list:
             setattr(self.__class__, name, property(fget=lambda self: self.change(self.data1, self.data2) ))
            
    def change(self, data1, data2):
        return data1 - data2
        
        
dync = DynamicProperties(['a', 'b'], 1, 2)
dync.add_properties()
print(dync.a == dync.change(1, 2)) # prints true 
print(dync.b == dync.change(1,2)) # prints true
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add more complexity to the member, `__getattr__ / __setattr__` gives you the string, so it can be interpreted as needed. The biggest "problem" doing this is that the return might no be consistent and piping it back to a library that expect an object to have a specific behavior can cause soft errors.

This example is not the same as yours, but it has the same concept, manipulate columns with members. To get a copy with changes a *set* is not needed, with a copy, modify and return, the new instance can be created with whatever needed.

For example, the `__getattr__` in this line will:

1. Check and interpret the string `xyz_mull_0`
2. Validate that the members and the operand exists
3. Make a copy of `data_a`
4. Modify the copy and return it

```py
var = data_a.xyz_mull_0()
```

This looks more complex that it actually is, with the same instance members its clear what it is doing, but the `_of` modifier needs a callback, this is because the `__getattr__` can only have one parameter, so it needs to save the `attr` and return a callback to be called with the other instance that then will call back to the `__getattr__` and complete the rest of the function.

```
import re

class FlexibleFrame:

    operand_mod = {
        'sub': lambda a, b: a - b,
        'add': lambda a, b: a + b,
        'div': lambda a, b: a / b,
        'mod': lambda a, b: a % b,
        'mull': lambda a, b: a * b,
    }

    @staticmethod
    def add_operand(name, func):
        if name not in FlexibleFrame.operand_mod.keys():
            FlexibleFrame.operand_mod[name] = func

    # This makes this class subscriptable 
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__dict__[item]

    # Uses:
    #   -> object.value
    #   -> object.member()
    #   -> object.<name>_<operand>_<name|int>()
    #   -> object.<name>_<operand>_<name|int>_<flow>()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+(_of)?$', attr):
            seg = attr.split('_')
            var_a, operand, var_b = seg[0:3]

            # If there is a _of: the second operand is from the other 
            # instance, the _of is removed and a callback is returned 
            if len(seg) == 4:
                self.__attr_ref = '_'.join(seg[0:3])
                return self.__getattr_of

            # Checks if this was a _of attribute and resets it
            if self.__back_ref is not None:
                other = self.__back_ref
                self.__back_ref = None
                self.__attr_ref = None
            else:
                other = self

            if var_a not in self.__dict__:
                raise AttributeError(
                    f'No match of {var_a} in (primary) {__class__.__name__}'
                )
            if operand not in FlexibleFrame.operand_mod.keys():
                raise AttributeError(
                    f'No match of operand {operand}'
                )

            # The return is a copy of self, if not the instance
            # is getting modified making x = a.b() useless
            ret = FlexibleFrame(**self.__dict__)

            # Checks if the second operand is a int
            if re.match(r'^\d+$', var_b) :
                ref_b_num = int(var_b)
                for i in range(len(self[var_a])):
                    ret[var_a][i] = FlexibleFrame.operand_mod[operand](
                        self[var_a][i], ref_b_num
                    )
            elif var_b in other.__dict__:
                for i in range(len(self[var_a])):
                    # out_index = operand[type](in_a_index, in_b_index)
                    ret[var_a][i] = FlexibleFrame.operand_mod[operand](
                        self[var_a][i], other[var_b][i]
                    )
            else:
                raise AttributeError(
                    f'No match of {var_b} in (secondary) {__class__.__name__}'
                )

            # This swaps the .member to a .member()
            # it also adds and extra () in __getattr_of
            return lambda: ret
            # return ret

        if attr in self.__dict__:
            return self[attr]

        raise AttributeError(
            f'No match of {attr} in {__class__.__name__}'
        )

    def __getattr_of(self, other):
        self.__back_ref = other
        return self.__getattr__(self.__attr_ref)()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__back_ref = None
        self.__attr_ref = None

        #TODO: Check if data columns match in size
        # if not, implement column_<name>_filler=<default>
        for i in kwargs:
            self.__dict__[i] = kwargs[i]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_a = FlexibleFrame(**{
        'abc': [i for i in range(10)],
        'nmv': [i for i in range(10)],
        'xyz': [i for i in range(10)],  
    })
    data_b = FlexibleFrame(**{
        'fee': [i + 10 for i in range(10)],
        'foo': [i + 10 for i in range(10)],     
    })

    FlexibleFrame.add_operand('set', lambda a, b: b)

    var = data_a.xyz_mull_0()
    var = var.abc_set_xyz()
    var = var.xyz_add_fee_of(data_b)
```

As a extra thing, lambdas in python have [this](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=lambda#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) thing, so it can make difficult using them when self changes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're bending the language to do weird things. I'd take it as a smell that your code is probably getting convoluted but I'm not saying there would never be a use-case for it so here is a minimal example of how to do it:

```py
class Obj:
    def _df_change(self, arg):
        print('change', arg)


class DynAttributes(Obj):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._df_change(name)


class Something:
    difference = DynAttributes()


a = Something()

b = Obj()

assert a.difference.hello == b._df_change('hello')
```

Answer (score -1):

When calling `setattr` , use `self.__class__` instead of `self`

Code sample:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,names : List[str]):
        for name in names:
            setattr(self.__class__,name,property(fget=self.__create_getter(name)))

    def __create_getter(self,name: str):
        def inner(self):
            print(f"invoking {name}")
            return 10
        return inner

a = A(['x','y'])

print(a.x + 1)
print(a.y + 2)
```

Comment: This had wrong indentation, but it was pretty clear how it should be indented, so I fixed that. The idea is good and correct, but the explanation here is quite sparse.