# Accessing `self` and method name from dynamically-created methods

Tags: python

I have a class of which several methods could be dynamically generated, which would save some boilerplate:

```
class A:
    def save_foo(self, **kwargs):
        do_foo_stuff_here()
    def save_bar(self, **kwargs):
        do_bar_stuff_here()
    def save_foobar(self, **kwargs):
        do_foobar_stuff_here()
```

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929543/how-can-i-dynamically-create-class-methods-for-a-class-in-python) taught me about that I can create the methods using

```
class A():
    pass

def _method_generator(cls, **kwargs):
    if method_name == "save_foo":
        do_foo_stuff_here()
    elif method_name == "save_foo":
        do_bar_stuff_here()
    elif method_name == "save_foobar":
        do_foobar_stuff_here()

for method_name in ["save_foo", "save_bar", "save_foobar"]:
    setattr(A, method_name, classmethod(_method_generator))
```

My problem is twofold:

1. From `_method_generator`, I can access the class via `cls`, but I don't see a way to access the instance, e.g. `self`. How can I do this?
2. In order to replicate the logic of `save_foo`, `save_foo`, `save_foobar` from `_method_generator`, I need to know which was called. I've seen answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method), but that gives me `_method_generator`, not the method/attribute that called it. How can I get this?

Comment: I very much doubt dynamical code generation is gonna save you boilerplate code.

Comment: Dont convert the functions with `classmethod` if you dont want a class method

Comment: it's not clear at all what are you trying to achieve, what is the relationship with `do_stuff_here` and the `do_xy_stuff_here`? Could you clarify it?

Comment: The idea is to have `do_stuff_here()` to have something like `if method_name == `...  and according to which foo/bar/foobar was called, apply the appropriate logic.

Comment: That's not what any of the answers in the linked question is recommending.

Comment: instead of a "switch case" inside the body of a function make a dictionary `{"foo": lambda self: do_foo_stuff_here(), ...}`... and consider also the option of dynamical class creation with with parametric form of `type`

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions.

Comment: Neither of your questions make sense in context, because you aren't defining anything equivalent to the original class `A`.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be misunderstanding a mix of various answers in the question you linked to. You would write something like this (which is really just a desugaring of the `class` statement in the first place):

```
def m1(self, **kwargs):
    ...

def m2(self, **kwargs):
    ...

def m3(self, **kwargs):
    ...

class A:
    pass

for name, func in zip(["save_foo", "save_bar", "save_foobar"], [m1, m2, m3]):
    setattr(A, name, func)
```

Methods are just function-valued class attributes.

---

Your `_method_generator` would have to actually generate functions that accept the arguments you want, and pass them to the underlying implementations as necessary.

```
def _method_generator(method_name):
    if method_name == "save_foo":
        return lambda self, **kwargs: do_foo_stuff_here()
    elif method_name == "save_bar":
        return lambda self, **kwargs: do_bar_stuff_here()
    elif method_name == "save_foobar":
        return lambda self, **kwargs: do_foobar_stuff_here()

for method_name in ["save_foo", "save_bar", "save_foobar"]:
    setattr(A, method_name, _method_generator(method_name))
```

Comment: How do I get at the instance `self` from `_method_generator`?

Comment: You don't; the function that `_method_generator` returns is the function that expects `self`. (And ultimately, it's the `method` object *that* function produces that handles passing an argument to the underlying function. That is, consider `a = A(); m = a.save_foo`, then look at the values of `m.__self__` and `m.__func__`.  The call `m(3)` is basically the same as `m.__func__(m.__self__, 3)`.

Comment: `_method_generator("save_foo")` returns `lambda self, **kwargs: do_foo_stuff_here()`; it does not itself call `do_foo_stuff_here` and return the result.

Comment: Thanks. Your code showed me how to get what I wanted. If you update your answer to include the following, I'll accept it: ```class A:
    pass

def _method_generator(method_name):

    def _generic_method(self, method_name, **kwargs):
        print(f"{self}, {method_name}, {kwargs}")

    return lambda self, **kwargs: _generic_method(self, method_name, **kwargs)

for method_name in ["save_foo", "save_bar", "save_foobar"]:
    setattr(A, method_name, _method_generator(method_name))

a = A()
a.save_foo(key=2)
a.save_bar(value=3)
a.save_foobar(something=4)
```